# read and type content of srt file from url

Tags: java, android

I have an api which contain these two keys and values:

```
videoUrl:http://ip.json/master.m3u8
srtUrl:http://ip/The_Last_Lions.srt
```

and I already finish the networking and parsing and play the video in media player

now I'm trying to display the texts of srt file with video view as a subtitle for that video

so I use **AsynsTask** like this:

```
    public class ShashaDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<DetailItem>> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                mLoadingIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<DetailItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
                if (params.length == 0) {
                    return null;
                }

                String searchUrl = params[0];
                URL channelRequestUrl = NetworkShasha.buildUrl(searchUrl);

                try {
                    String results = NetworkShasha.getResponseFromHttpUrl(channelRequestUrl);

                    ArrayList<DetailItem> simpleJsonTVData = JsonShashaDetail.getSimpleMovieStringsFromJson(ShashaDetail.this, results);

                String srt = simpleJsonTVData.get(0).getSrt();
                Log.d("tag", "test: " + srts);
                al = new ArrayList<>();

                try{
                    URL urlsrt = new URL(srts);
                    URLConnection conn = urlsrt.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.connect();

                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    String line;

                    try {
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            al.add(line);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        br.close();
                    }
                }catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                    return simpleJsonTVData;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

I already define the ArrayList al; in the beginning of class

and when I log or debug the srt variable the value is true link like this:

> http://ip/The_Last_Lions.srt

then the **onPostExecute**:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<DetailItem> results) {
            if (results != null && !results.equals("")) {
               String url = results.get(0).getUrladaptive();

             String finalSrt = al.get(0);
            InputStream srtStream = null;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                srtStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(finalSrt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
```

you can see I convert the string finalSrt to InputStream srtStream because it required to use InputStream type here:

```
videoView.setMediaController(playerControlView.getMediaControllerWrapper());
                    videoView.seekTo(position);
                  videoView.start();

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        videoView.addSubtitleSource(srtStream,
                                MediaFormat.createSubtitleFormat("text/srt",Locale.ENGLISH.getLanguage()));
                    }
```

so I got this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

then solve it using this code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_shasha_detail);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
            {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
```

but now when I run the app it just crush when open this activity and I get this error:

```
beginning of crash
09-18 08:21:19.271 25904-25904/giga.net.world.GN E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: giga.net.world.GN, PID: 25904
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at giga.net.world.GN.ShashaDetail$ShashaDetails.onPostExecute(ShashaDetail.java:513)
        at giga.net.world.GN.ShashaDetail$ShashaDetails.onPostExecute(ShashaDetail.java:450)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

the problem is with these lines:

```
public class ShashaDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<DetailItem>> {
```

and:

```
String finalSrt = al.get(0);
```

and this is the whole other exception from logcat:

```
09-18 09:15:29.267 9637-9637/giga.net.world.GN E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
09-18 09:15:37.108 9637-9653/giga.net.world.GN W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ip/The_Last_Lions.srt
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
        at giga.net.world.GN.ShashaDetail$ShashaDetails.doInBackground(ShashaDetail.java:481)
        at giga.net.world.GN.ShashaDetail$ShashaDetails.doInBackground(ShashaDetail.java:450)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

I can't understand why it's out of bound while if I open the link directly in browser the srt file downloaded in my device

also I tried to upload srt file in public IP and you can check it from this link:

> http://172.104.238.92/text.srt

and change the code to network with this static url by add this line:

```
String srts = "http://172.104.238.92/text.srt";
```

instead of the old one:

```
String srts = simpleJsonTVData.get(0).getSrt();
```

then when I run the ap and open it I get same error and this is the logcat of it:

```
09-18 10:42:48.219 11961-11961/giga.net.world.GN E/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : Exception_1 = java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.qualcomm.qti.Performance" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
09-18 10:42:54.212 11961-11995/giga.net.world.GN W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://172.104.238.92/text.srt
09-18 10:42:54.325 11961-11961/giga.net.world.GN E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: giga.net.world.GN, PID: 11961
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
        at giga.net.world.GN.ShashaDetail$ShashaDetails.onPostExecute(ShashaDetail.java:514)
        at giga.net.world.GN.ShashaDetail$ShashaDetails.onPostExecute(ShashaDetail.java:450)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:660)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:677)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

don't know what's the problem

Comment: `onPostExecute` is performed in main thread, you can't do any network in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: I already tried to do the network in the doInBackgroun and display the content in onPostExecute so I edit the code to this case please see the question again because it leads me to the same problem @Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: show the full exception stacktrace. It will at least show on which line it happened

Comment: I add the full exception read it please @Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: your `al` length is 0. You didn't add anything to it. Check the logcat for other exceptions that you log with ` e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: but why it's 0 while I add to it at this line: al.add(line); in the doInBackground? I edit the question and add whole other exceptions can you check it please @Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: if you wrote that code, it does not mean that it will be executed. As you see in exception - `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ip/The_Last_Lions.srt`. Probably your URL is incorrect, or you are trying to access LAN IP from WAN.

Comment: actually the url is correct because when I click on it from the logcat window it opened in browser then the file downloaded in me device and yes it's LAN IP and now I'm open internet from the same LAN as I told you if I open the link in browser it open correctly and downloaded and also the videoUrl is work fine and the video is start playing normally while both the srt and video at the same LAN IP but to prove that for you so I just upload srt file on public server ip and I edit the question by add the new case of srt at the end of question check it please @Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: clicking in logcat will open it in **the PC browser**, but your phone has no access to it I think. Try opening it in the phone browser. If you are using LAN ip, you can stop hiding it, and show it.

Comment: also does your app has internet permission?

Comment: now I just copy the link and open it in the browser of the phone and it's opened in the browser then downloaded the file too. now forget the private IP while I add file on public IP I will focus on make it work with this static link: [link]http://172.104.238.92/text.srt first and yes of course I have internet connection that's why the video is playing and the whole other networking is successful, now what should I do with this strange problem? @Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: I can't say anything from here. You just have to deal with `java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://ip/The_Last_Lions.srt` first

Comment: can I deal with `09-18 10:42:54.212 11961-11995/giga.net.world.GN W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://172.104.238.92/text.srt`
 first because it's on public IP but it gave me same error so how to deal with it =( @Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: sure, that's what I meant - your app has to be able to access the file before everything, and for some reason it can't